# Google maps setZoom not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a weird problem. I'm fetching data on my page and then updating my map with my new data.

When the page first loads I initialize the map with initializeMap(). Then I load the data initializeMapData(). Subsequently, if I load the data after the initial page load (with ajax) I don't re-initialize the map, I just call initializeMapData().

The problem is sometimes the zoom in the map doesn't reflect the value I provide, although I'm printing out the zoom level via getZoom(), and it shows the correct value, it's not correct on the map. It looks like it doesn't update it (so it's the previous map zoom level), even though the getZoom shows the correct value.

*FYI* -- If I initialize the map intitializeMap() each time I fetch data via ajax and update that data it works, but then I see the map flicker from the re-initialize, which I don't want. I'm just trying to avoid this and feel like it should work!

Here are two main methods. The first and second method will always get called on page load, and only the second method gets called on an ajax call to update the data in the map.

UPDATED! -- I found the area that's causing the issue. IT's clearing the listener for the zoom changed event! But if I remove clearing it, then the event gets created and called multiple times every time update the data. Not good! Is this a bug?

```js
google.maps.event.clearListeners(scope.map, 'zoom_changed');

google.maps.event.addListener(scope.map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
  //if (scope.zoomFlag === "user") {
  //    var zoomLevel = scope.map.getZoom();
  //    scope.mapType = getMapType(zoomLevel);
  //    scope.getEvents();
  //}

});
```

```js
scope.initializeMap();
scope.initializeMapData();
```

Here is the first method

```js
scope.initializeMap = function() {
  scope.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('eventMap'), {
    scrollwheel: false,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    streetViewControl: false,
    disableDoubleClickZoom: true //,
      //zoom: scope.getZoom()
  });
};
```

Here is the second method

```js
scope.initializeMapData = function() {
  // clear all markers
  for (var i = 0; i < scope.markers.length; i++) {
    scope.markers[i].setMap(null);
  }

  var latLng = {
    lng: scope.longitude,
    lat: scope.latitude
  };

  // set center
  scope.map.setCenter(latLng);

  // set zoom
  //scope.zoomFlag = "api";
  console.log("before:" + scope.map.getZoom());
  var zoomLevel = scope.getZoom();
  console.log("level:" + zoomLevel);
  scope.map.setZoom(zoomLevel);
  console.log("after:" + scope.map.getZoom());
  //scope.zoomFlag = "user";

  // create center marker (for testing)
  var centerMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latLng,
    map: scope.map,
    draggable: false,
    icon: '/Images/searchQuery_pin_distance.png'
  });
  scope.markers.push(centerMarker);

  // clear center circle
  scope.mapCircle !== undefined ? scope.mapCircle.setMap(null) : null;

  var centerCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
    strokeColor: 'transparent',
    //strokeOpacity: 1,
    //strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: 'lightgrey', //'#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.50,
    map: scope.map,
    center: latLng,
    radius: getRadius()
  });
  scope.mapCircle = centerCircle;

  // clear click event listeners first
  google.maps.event.clearListeners(scope.map, 'click');

  for (var i = 0; i < scope.mapData.length; i++) {
    var event = scope.mapData[i];
    var contentString = event.Title;
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      //content: contentString,
      maxWidth: 200
    });
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: {
        lat: event.Latitude,
        lng: event.Longitude
      },
      map: scope.map //,
        //title: event.Title
    });
    scope.markers.push(marker);
    //marker.addListener('click', function () {
    //    infowindow.open(scope.map, marker);
    //});
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, contentString) {
      return function() {
        infowindow.setContent(contentString);
        infowindow.open(scope.map, marker);
      }
    })(marker, contentString));
  }

  // clear drag end event listener
  google.maps.event.clearListeners(scope.map, 'dragend');

  google.maps.event.addListener(scope.map, 'dragend', function() {
    var LatLng = scope.map.getCenter();

    var url = window.location.href.replace("latitude=" + scope.latitude, "latitude=" + LatLng.lat()).replace("longitude=" + scope.longitude, "longitude=" + LatLng.lng()).replace(/\bPage=\d+/, "Page=1");

    scope.latitude = LatLng.lat();
    scope.longitude = LatLng.lng();
    scope.getEvents();

    scope.changeUrl('index', url);
  });

  // clear zoom event listener
  google.maps.event.clearListeners(scope.map, 'zoom_changed');

  google.maps.event.addListener(scope.map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
    //if (scope.zoomFlag === "user") {
    //    var zoomLevel = scope.map.getZoom();
    //    scope.mapType = getMapType(zoomLevel);
    //    scope.getEvents();
    //}

  });

  function getMapType(zoomLevel) {
    var mapType;
    switch (zoomLevel) {
      case 16:
        mapType = 'street_address';
        break;
      case 15:
        mapType = 'route';
        break;
      case 13:
        mapType = 'locality';
        break;
      case 8:
        mapType = 'administrative_area_level_2';
        break;
      case 6:
        mapType = 'administrative_area_level_1';
        break;
      case 3:
        mapType = 'country';
        break;
      case 3:
        mapType = 'continent';
        break;
      case 12:
      case 11:
      default:
        mapType = 'locality';
    }
    return mapType;
  };

  function getRadius() {
    var radius;
    switch (scope.mapType) {
      case 'street_address':
        radius = 500;
        break;
      case 'route':
        radius = 1200;
        break;
      case 'locality':
        radius = 4047;
        break;
      case 'administrative_area_level_2':
        radius = 8;
        break;
      case 'administrative_area_level_1':
        radius = 6;
        break;
      case 'country':
        radius = 4000000;
        break;
      case 'continent':
        radius = 4000000;
        break;
      default:
        radius = 4047;
    }
    return radius;
  };
};
```

and here is an additional method to get the zoom level

```js
scope.getZoom = function() {
  var zoom;
  switch (scope.mapType) {
    case 'street_address':
      zoom = 16;
      break;
    case 'route':
      zoom = 15;
      break;
    case 'postal_code':
      zoom = 13;
      break;
    case 'locality':
      zoom = 13;
      break;
    case 'administrative_area_level_2':
      zoom = 8;
      break;
    case 'administrative_area_level_1':
      zoom = 6;
      break;
    case 'country':
      zoom = 3;
      break;
    case 'continent':
      zoom = 3;
      break;
    default:
      zoom = 13;
  }
  return zoom;
};
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure why this works but it does.

```js
if (scope.listener !== undefined)
  scope.listener.remove();

scope.listener = google.maps.event.addListener(scope.map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
  // do stuff
});
```

But this screws up the zoom settings in the map

```js
google.maps.event.clearListeners(scope.map, 'zoom_changed');
```